# Does the Pyromancer sorcerer's Fiery Soul feature work with the Elemental Adept feat (fire damage) to effectively ignore immunity as well?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, sorcerer, damage-resistance, immunities

The [Pyromancer](https://media.wizards.com/2017/downloads/magic/Plane-Shift_Kaladesh.pdf#page=9) sorcerous origin from [*Plane Shift: Kaladesh*](https://media.wizards.com/2017/downloads/magic/Plane-Shift_Kaladesh.pdf) gains the Fiery Soul feature at 18th level. Part of its description says:

> [...] any spell or effect you create ignores resistance to fire damage and treats immunity to fire damage as resistance to fire damage.

The [Elemental Adept (Fire)](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/elemental-adept-fire) feat says (PHB, p. 166):

> Spells you cast ignore resistance to fire damage.

Would these two stack together to allow the user to completely ignore fire immunity (so Fiery Soul treats the immunity as resistance, and then Elemental Adept further allows you to ignore that)?
Or would Elemental Adept be useless to a pyromancer at 18th level, as they can already ignore resistances?

Comment: Related question about Fiery Soul stacking with itself: [Does the Pyromancer sorcerer's Fiery Soul feature totally bypass immunity to fire damage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/174987/does-the-pyromancer-sorcerers-fiery-soul-feature-totally-bypass-immunity-to-fir)

Comment: I've made some edits to the formatting and language, let me know if something is out of plae.

Comment: Note that the 6th level feature of the Pyromancer *already* has this effect: "In addition, spells you cast ignore resistance to fire damage." The Elemental Adept feat (fire) would be redundant. See my answer on the above linked question. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### These would stack.

The rules for combining game effects are found in the *Dungeon Master's Guide*:

> Different game features can affect a target at the same time. But when two or more game features have the same name, only the effects of one of them—the most potent one—apply while the durations of the effects overlap.

Fiery Soul and Elemental Adept are different features, so they both apply. Notably, they are both an "always on" sort of effect. Fiery Soul says:

> any spell or effect you create ignores resistance to fire damage and
> treats immunity to fire damage as resistance to fire damage.

So fiery soul would turn immunity into resistance, then Elemental Adept (Fire) says:

> Spells you cast ignore resistance to fire damage.

Different features, so they both apply. Fiery souls turns the immunity into resistance that Elemental Adept (Fire) ignores.

Comment: Order is significant in this case.

Comment: I don’t think it is. They’re both “always on” so to speak, so at any given time you can check if a target satisfies their conditions.

Comment: If you are facing a creature with fire immunity and apply Elemental Adept first it doesn't make a difference. Fiery soul would only reduce immunity to resistance.

Comment: And since they are both on all the time, the question is which is logically prior.